# Find out how many times the user has logged in

Tags: mysql, login, users

I'd like to determine how many times a user has logged in. Does WordPress retain that information or will I have to add a db entry every time they log-in?

```
if(is_user_logged_in() && ($logged_in_times == 2)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so.  You will need to do something like this (untested):

```
add_action("wp_login", "my_login_function");

function my_login_function($username){
   $userdata = get_user_by('login', $username);
   $n = get_user_meta($userdata->ID, "my_login_counter", true);
   if (! is_numeric($n)) $n = 0;
   $n = intval($n) + 1;
   update_user_meta($userdata->ID, "my_login_counter", $n);
}
```